# Storing data in 3 separate lists and parallel access

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to have the user input an ID number that matches the first list, and then pull the index-matching name and pay rate from the following 2 lists. However, it's not finding the employee ID in the list. I've tried a bunch of different loops, but it either completely errors out, let's a single number like "0" return values, or works like it does now - fine but doesn't match the first list.

This is for a class assignment, but I cannot find any examples in class or online that are similar to what I'm trying to do. I've tried a bunch of different loops in the employee_id_prompt section, but I cannot get it to work.

Can someone offer some guidance on how I can get it to match up the input to the first list, and return the matching values from the second and third list? I've tried a bunch of "for found in employee_id", "if input_employee_id in employee_id", etc., but I keep finding errors that I cannot figure out.

```
SIZE = 10
employee_id = [1001, 1002, 1003, 1004, 1005, 1006, 1007, 1008, 1009, 1010]
employee_name = ["A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I", "J"]
employee_pay = [17.75, 18.23, 19.42, 20.00, 21.50, 22.34, 23.74, 24.68, 24.75, 25.00]

def check_int(prompt):
    int_result = 0

    while True:
        try:
            int_result = int(input(prompt))
        except ValueError:
            print("This is outside the range or invalid. Please enter again.")
            continue
        else:
            break
    return int_result


def employee_id_prompt():
    input_employee_id = 0
    found = False
    index = 0

    while True:
        input_employee_id = check_int("Please enter your Employee ID number: ")
        while found == False and index <= SIZE - 1:
            if employee_id[index] == input_employee_id:
                found = True
            else:
                index = index + 1

        if found == True:
            print("Welcome " + employee_name[index] + ". Your current pay rate is $", + employee_pay[index],
              "an hour.")
            break
        else:
            print("I'm sorry, that Employee ID number is not recognized.")
            index = index + 1


employee_id_prompt()
```

Comment: This is actually not a good way to structure data, in three lists. In that case you should use some kind of record (object, tuple, namedtuple, etc.).

Answer (score 0):

It seems that `found` and `index` must be initialized inside the `while True` loop

```
while True:
    found = False
    index = 0
    input_employee_id = check_int("Please enter your Employee ID number: ")
    while index <= SIZE - 1:
        if employee_id[index] == input_employee_id:
            found = True
            break
        else:
            index = index + 1
```

With a little more experience of python, you'll prefer `list.index()` to search the list, as Coldspeed says.

Comment: Thank you! This worked. I see in my class example the two were initialized inside the while True statement, but it wasn't explained.

Comment: The reason is that every time you run `input_employee_id = check_int(...)`, a new employee ID is being handled and the search must restart from fresh.

Comment: @Kethi When there are better ways to do the same thing you are doing, why not think about using them?

Comment: @Coldspeed Because it takes years of programming to learn the best way to do things. Students must learn slowly.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation as well.  This is still fairly early in my first course on Python, so yes, its very simplistic. My program works now, but everyone's explanations let me know of other ways to do the same thing, so I can continue working on it as well as I'm learning.

Comment: @Kethi A good part of learning a language consists in learning the contents of existing libraries, starting with python's standard libraries in our case. As these libraries contain hundreds of features and thousands of details, there is no short way to learn them.